# PHP header redirect works on Apache, but not Nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I have a contact form that will resubmit data if you refresh the page, so I added `header("Location: http://www.example.com/form.php");` at the end of it so the page redirects back to itself and ultimately resets the form, preventing it from being submitted multiple times. It works exactly how I want it to on my local Apache server, but when I use the same code on an Nginx server, the form stops working altogether. Removing `header("Location: http://www.example.com/form.php");` allows the form to work on the Nginx server, but then I will still have the resubmitting issue.

Is there a way to get header redirects to work with Nginx? If not, is there an alternative way to prevent my form from being resubmitted when people refresh the page?

Note: I tried adding `header("HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently");` on the line above `header("Location: http://www.example.com/form.php");`, as that was a possible solution I found, but it didn't solve anything.

EDIT: I put example.com in my post as I didn't want to put the real URL I am redirecting to.

Here is some code:

```
 <?php
        // define variables and set to empty values
        $firstnameErr = $lastnameErr = $emailErr = $companyErr = "";
        $firstname = $lastname = $email = $company = $comments = "";


        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $error = false;
            //Verifying first name input
            if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
                $firstnameErr = "First name is required";
                $error = true;
            } else {
                $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
                // Check if first name only contains letters and whitespace
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $firstname)) {
                    $firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
                    $error = true;
                }

            }

            //Verifying last name input
            if (empty($_POST["lastname"])) {
                $lastnameErr = "Last name is required";
                $error = true;
            } else {
                $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
                // Check if last name only contains letters and whitespace
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $lastname)) {
                    $lastnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
                    $error = true;
                }
            }

            //Verifying email input
            if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                $emailErr = "Email is required";
                $error = true;
            } else {
                $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                // Check if email is well-formed
                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
                    $error = true;
                }
            }

            //Verifying company input
            if (empty($_POST["company"])) {
                $companyErr = "Company name is required";
                $error = true;
            } else {
                $company = test_input($_POST["company"]);
            }

            //Verifying comments input (empty input is allowed)
            if (empty($_POST["comments"])) {
                $comments = "";
            } else {
                $comments = test_input($_POST["comments"]);
            }

            if (!$error){
            // Email sent to me
            mail("example@example.com", "Email subject", "Email message");
            // Confirmation email to potential client
            mail("example@example.com", "Email subject", "Email message");
            }
            // Loads new, empty form (otherwise refreshing page will resubmit form)
            header("HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location: http://www.example.com/request.php");
        }


        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }
      ?>


 <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    <label>Name*</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First" size="20">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $firstnameErr;?></span>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last" size="20" class="form-control">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $lastnameErr;?></span>
    <label>Email*</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" size="50" class="form-control">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
    <label>Company*</label>
    <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company" size="50" class="form-control">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $companyErr;?></span>
    <label>Comments</label>
    <textarea rows="4" name="comments" placeholder="Comments..." class="form-control"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn">
</form>
```

Comment: That's just where I put the URL that I have it redirecting to. Didn't want to put the actual URL in there. I'll modify my post to make that more clear

Comment: I doubt it's nginx problem. Could u post code example, it's hard to understand anything and check if you are not returning something before location header is send.

Comment: It works perfectly on Apache, but not on Nginx. I will post some code

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', false, 301);    
header('Location: http://www.thedigideck.com/request.php');    
exit();
```

Or just use this redirect function

```
function redirect($url) {
  $content = sprintf('<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=%1$s" />

    <title>Redirecting to %1$s</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Redirecting to <a href="%1$s">%1$s</a>.
  </body>
  </html>', htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

  header('Location: ' . $url);

  die($content);
}
```

So it sets redirect header and returns body with redirect if the header didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Comment: Is server using FastCGI ?

Comment: I will figure that out. Is that something that needs to be used?

Comment: Yes, it is using FastCGI.

Comment: No just on nginx php isn't loaded as module like on apache, options are FastCgi or PHP-FPM. And in a lot of post i saw different variations of redirect with fastcgi. But what are the headers in browser when u set the redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably related to the hosting server nginx is running on, not the fact that there is a difference in nginx and apache. The header function must be called at the beginning of the page, which works on localhost, but not when wrapped by a 3rd party host.

You could try using a meta tag for the redirect such as:
    echo "http://domain.com'>";

Comment: so just try putting that code in place of the header functions? Or does that need to be at the beginning of the page?

Comment: try that in place of the header functions

Comment: Interesting. I submitted an empty form to test it out, and error messages popped up saying that I can't leave fields empty, just like I want it to, but those messages disappear after a second. On my localhost, with the old code the error messages would remain on the page. Seems like it's close to fixing it, but just not quite there yet.

Comment: Are your error message html5 validation errors or your custom error checking?

Comment: I think your issue here is logic. You are submitting a blank form, which is going into your if statement to check what was in the form. There are errors so it is showing them, but you are still refreshing the page if there are errors. I think you should just refresh the page if there are no errors.

Comment: No, my code only refreshes the page if there are no errors.

Comment: In the code above it shows the check: 'if (!$error){ ... }' then redirect. The redirect should be in this conditional.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found that it was because a `header("Status: 200 OK", false, 200);` before the header to redirect.
So I added a condition not to display the header 200 if I know that I will have to redirect:

```
    if(!isset($_GET['utm_source'])) { //Header will be Redirect 301 from global_cookies.inc.php
        header("Status: 200 OK", false, 200);
    }
```

**Note**: With Apache I had not this problem and could redirect even after a header 200.